# Comparing 2 strings and getting the error expected expression

Tags: c, string, compare, cs50

I am working on a project where you enter a name and the initials are printed. When I try to compare strings I get an "expected expression" error. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
   printf("Name: ");
   string name = GetString();
   printf("\n");

   int length = strlen(name);
   string compair1 = " ";
   for(int l = 0;l<=length;l++) {
      char compair2 = name[l];
      int  res = strcmp(compair1,&compair2);
      if(res == 0) {
         printf("found blank space");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `for(int l = 0; name[l];l++) { if(name[l] == ' ') printf("found blank space\n"); }`

Comment: You can't just take the address of a single `char` and use it as an argument to `strcmp`, because it's not null-terminated.  In general, this can cause a segmentation violation.  If you just want to compare a single character, you can use `int res = compair1[0] == compair2;`

Comment: what does & do in "int res = strcmp(compair1, &compair2);"

Comment: @MarcusMardis &compair2 means "the address of compair2". So you are passing strcmp the address of the char variable, and strcmp treats it as the beginning of a null terminated string, which it is not.

Comment: You can [see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) how to use strcmp.

Comment: `if(strchr(name, ' ') /* or if(strstr(name, " ")) */ printf("found blank space\n");`

Comment: That string typedef in cs50.h is silly.

Comment: I know BLUEPIXY already suggested a fix for your `for` loop, but for future reference, you've got an off-by-one error there. The condition for iterating through an array should be like `l<length` if you're starting at 0.

Answer (score 1):

- If u jst want to find space then you can simply do like this:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <ctype.h>

  int main(void)
  {
     printf("Name: ");
     char name[20];
     gets(name);
     printf("\n");

    int length = strlen(name);
    for(int l = 0;l < length;l++)
    {
        if(name[l] == ' ')
        printf("found blank space");
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Absolutely correct.  Two caveats: 1) [gets()](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1049157810&id=1043284351) is Bad.  A preferred alternative is `fgets(mystring, len, stdin)`.  2) Using [strchr()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr) would simplify the code (and eliminate the entire "for" loop).  +1 for *NOT* using "cs50.h" ;)

Comment: @paulsm4: Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

You should look up [`strtok()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html). Here is an example for you.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "Bufford T Justice";
    char *token;
    char space = ' ';
    int count = 0;

    token = strtok(str, &space);

    while( token != NULL ) 
    {
        printf( "%s\n", token );
        token = strtok(NULL, &space);
        if( token )
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("Number of spaces = %d\n", count);
    return(0);
}
```

From this snippet it's only a matter of a handful of lines to determine the initials of the entered name.

Note: If you don't want the string to be modified by `strtok()`, you could use `strchr()` with a few minor changes.